# Have a nested dictionary in python, and would like to fine an efficient way to append to it

Tags: dictionary, nested, python

I am looking to find the best pythonic way to do this.

Nested dictionary looks something like this (main script):

```
my_dict = { test: { 
                   test_a: 'true',
                   test_b: 'true
                  }
```

I am importing a module that has functions that return numeric values.

I am looking for a way to append to the my_dict dictionary from the dictionary returned from the module.

i.e. functions from module:

```
def testResults1():
  results = 3129282
  return results

def testResults2():
  results = 33920230
  return results

def combineResults():
  Would like to combine results, and return a dictionary. Dictionary returned is:
  # Looking for best way to do this.

  test_results = { 'testresults1': 3129282, 
                   'testresults2': 33920230
                  }
```

I then want to append the test_results dictionary to my_dict.
Looking for best way to do this as well.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why does the nesting matter?  Do you want your new dict to be inserted at the "top level" of `my_dict`, or under `test`?

Comment: what's final expected value of my_dict?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the `dict.update()` method?

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> d2 = {'c': 3}
>>> d.update(d2)
>>> d
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Comment: Ah.. ok.. this this will work.. I can use d.update(myfunction). I think this will fair well for the 2nd part of my question. For the 1st part.. what would you recommend for combining the dictionary results within the external module I am calling? Thanks you again for the info.

Comment: I am inserting the dictionary into a nosql database, and I need the dictionary nested for the purpose of organization.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_dict = {}

def testResults1():
  results = 3129282
  return results

def testResults2():
  results = 33920230
  return results

def combineResults():
  suite = [testResults1, testResults2]

  return dict((test.__name__, test()) for test in suite)  

my_dict.update(combineResults())
print my_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections
my_dict = collections.defaultdict(lambda: {})

def add_values(key, inner_dict):
    my_dict[key].update(inner_dict)
```

You can read about `collections.defaultdict` in the library docs [here](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).